# LINQ-2-SQL and 'char' values

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have the following LINQ-to-SQL query:

```
from cms in ConsignmentMarginBreakdowns.Where(a => a.BreakdownType == 'S')
from cmc in ConsignmentMarginBreakdowns.Where(a => a.BreakdownType == 'C')
where cms.TripNumber == cmc.TripNumber && cms.Depot == cmc.Depot && cms.TripDate == cmc.TripDate
select new
{
    NTConsignment = cms.NTConsignment,
    Depot = cms.Depot,
    TripNumber = cms.TripNumber,
    TripDate = cms.TripDate,
    Sales = cms.Value,
    Costs = cmc.Value,
    Margin = cms.Value - cmc.Value
}
```

The 'BreakdownType' field is of 'char(1)' type in SQL Server 2008. For some reason, the query brings back no results as it is. To get it to bring back results, I need to change the top 2 lines to the following, which I imagine lowers the speed of the query:

```
from cms in ConsignmentMarginBreakdowns.Where(a => a.BreakdownType.ToString() == "S")
from cmc in ConsignmentMarginBreakdowns.Where(a => a.BreakdownType.ToString() == "C")
```

Why is this?

Comment: for the query that didn't work... what TSQL was generated? (either use a sql trace, or set `cms.Log = Console.Out;` or similar)

Comment: can i know what is the datatype of `BreakdownType` in your datacontext class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say, "The 'BreakdownType' field is of `char(1)` type in SQL Server 2008", what means that it's a "Fixed-length, non-Unicode character data with a length of n bytes" (in your case 1), it actually doesn't say that it's a "char" just because of the length of 1.

See [MSDN Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The mapping of LINQ to SQL datatypes says that a char field in SQL is mapped to string in LINQ. So you have to convert to string before using it.